# Avoid duplicates in SFDMU Insert

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, sfdmu

I'm currently using SFDMU to deploy data in an automated way in a pipeline.

Until now, the pipeline always used the `Upsert` operation in our `export.json` file. I.e

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "query": "SELECT Id, Phone, TestObject3__c FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'TEST_ACC_%'",
            "operation": "Upsert",
            "externalId": "Name"
        },
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to introduce the `Insert` mode in my pipeline, because existing data should not be overridden in some scenarios. However, this `Insert` operation is not working as I would expect, as it duplicates rows, instead of not inserting a record if it already exists. That causes frequent issues in data duplication and unique fields.

According to [SFDMU docs](https://help.sfdmu.com/full-documentation/configuration-and-running/full-exportjson-format): `"Insert" - creates new records on the target org even old versions of these records already exist.`

What should be the way to use SFDMU in `Insert` mode avoiding duplication? Is using `Upsert` my only resource?

Note: Same question in SFDMU repository ([link](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility/issues/529)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer of the SFDMU. This feature has been already implemented and you have a OOTB way to avoid inserting duplicated records. Use the ScriptObject.skipExistingRecords=true. Please refer: https://help.sfdmu.com/full-documentation/configuration-and-running/full-exportjson-format

Comment: I am having trouble getting skipExistingRecords to work.  It keeps inserting even though existing should be Id'd via the email externalId